conditional expectation confusion
This is how conditional expectation is defined in my probability textbook. 
On its own, it makes sense, but I have one question. Is E[X|G] a random variable on $(\Sigma, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, or is it only defined on the sub sigma-algebra $G$?
I think the former, because the integral in condition (ii), which has $E[X|G](w)$ in it, only seems to make sense if E[X|G] is defined on the full sigma-algebra. Would really appreciate any clarity on this. Thank you!

The domain of a random variable is the sample space, not  any sigma algebra. So asking if your r.v. is deinfed on the sub-sigma algebra does not even make sense.

A random variable is defined on the underlying set of the probability space, it is simply a function $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. It doesn't make sense to ask if it is defind in the sub-$\sigma$-algebra, since variables are not defined on $\sigma$-algebras, but on the underlying set of the space. A reasonable question to be asked is if it is a random variable, that is, if it's measurable. Well, this is precisely what the first item of the definition tells you.
For some intuition, I like to think that $\sigma$-algebras hold information. They are, of course, the set of possible events. A random-variable defined on a probability spaces transforms information: it takes abstract objects and events defined in the sample space and turns them into numerical values that we can work with. One could ask the question: knowing the expected value of a random variable over all possible events implies knowing the value of this same random variable at every point? Can the random variable be recovered by the information about how it behaves on events?
The answer is, almost (pun intended). We know from measure theory that if the expected value of two random variables on every event is the same, then the two variables are almost equal, that is, they differ in a set of measure zero. The question now becomes: can we do it with "less information"? If we exclude some events, i.e., take a sub-$\sigma$-algebra, can the random variable still be recovered?
The conditional expectation is precisely an attempt to do this. If $X$ is a random variable in the probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb{P})$, then the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[X \mid \Sigma']$ of $X$ with respect to some sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma'$ is a random variable that is the best approximation for $X$ with just the information given to us by the events of $\Sigma'$. It can, therefore, only be measurable in $\Sigma'$, and the second item in the definition says precisely that $\mathbb{E}[X\mid\Sigma']$ and $X$ have the same mean over the sets of $\Sigma'$.
